# Which was the first sci-fi/fantasy movie to feature epic final battle?

Tags: history-of

Epic final battles have become a major part of blockbusters nowadays, with most franchises like Avengers, Avatar, Lord of the Rings, Harry Potter and Star Wars ending their films with an epic final battle featuring absolute mayhem, and basically two sides with large participants fighting.

So which was the first sci-fi/fantasy movie to do that? that is feature an epic final battle.
I couldnt go any further than Lord of the Rings.

Comment: The software for multiplying the film-extras kicked-in about that time (may even have been developed in-part for that film). Can you clarify what you mean by "epic". Reason I ask, the silent-era version of Spartacus (not Sci-Fi-Fantasy, but just an example) had what are regarded as epic battle scenes in the arena. Your epic may not be my epic, can you clarify.

Comment: A belief in a final battle between good and evil with cinematic special effects goes at least back to the Bible in the Book of Revelation. Probably Zoroastrianism, even. It is natural that people would write fiction with similar ideas. All that happened was that budgets and technology in movies took some time to catch up.

Comment: well, @JiminyCricket., by epic I mean a large number of people on both sides, basically good vs evil , akin to the movies i mentioned . I dont care if the people in the battle were actual human extras or digitally made.

Comment: The Kurukshetra War (Mahābhārata War) from Bhakta Vidur (1921) would almost certainly be a contender - if it still existed. IMDB pro  may reveal further details, but the numbers of extras on both sides are seemingly lost to the void of unrecorded history.

Comment: You couldn’t go further back than *Lord of the Rings*? Does *Star Wars* not count as an epic final battle?? If not that, then what about *Return of the Jedi*? There are probably earlier examples but those are surely contenders

Comment: @ToddWilcox, actually no because as i said a "large number of participants on both sides", in new hope it was just fighter pilots against the tie fighters and they were still countable, but yes forgive my exclusion of return of the jedi

Comment: @Adamant The question is about cinema, so biblical epic battles from *the page* would not be an acceptable answer?

Comment: @JiminyCricket., Bhakta Vidur was actually banned in india, because the main character was similar to Gandhi and the British government didnt like it

Comment: Would scale models representing people count? This website https://www.filmsite.org/pre20sintro2.html mentions that films about the Spanish-american war in 1898 were produced in this method. I've not found a 'fantasy' film set about this conflict, but there may be some contenders

Comment: @shanu  Ihpoe that you have seen my answer and have been looking at some of the earlier movies in my list to see if they count.

Comment: @M.A.Golding, Yes, i have seen your answer, i took so much time to accept it because i had to first check out a trip to the moon

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Answering purely for science fiction movies and not including fantasy movies, movies ending with battles at the end go back aat least as far as the 1950s.

*The War of the Worlds* (1953) ended not with a bang but a whimper.  Other fifties science fiction movies ended with battles.

1950s Science fiction movies ending with big battles included:

*Battle in Outer Space* (1959). https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Battle_in_Outer_Space

*The Mysterians* (1957). https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Mysterians

*Earth vs the Flying saucers* (1956). https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Earth_vs._the_Flying_Saucers

*Invaders From Mars* (1953).https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Invaders_from_Mars_(1953_film)

I also note that an enemy attack destroys an inhabited planet near the end of *This Island Earth* (1955). https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/This_Island_Earth

Other 50s science fiction movies ended with smaller scale battles with the fate of the protagonists and often the entire Earth at stake.

*Teenagers From Outer Space* (1959). https://www.imdb.com/title/tt0053337/

*It: The Terror From Beyond Space* (1958). https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/It!_The_Terror_from_Beyond_Space

*Fiend Without a Face* (1958).https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fiend_Without_a_Face

*The Trollenberg Terror*/*The Crawling Eye* (1958).https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Trollenberg_Terror

*The Thing from Another World* (1951).https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Thing_from_Another_World

And there may have been climactic battle scenes in earlier science fiction movies.

The climax of *Things to Come* (1936) features a mob seeking to destroy a giant space cannon before it can launch a manned flight around the Moon.

[https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Things_to_Come#:~:text=Things%20to%20Come%20(also%20known,and%20written%20by%20H.%20G.%20Wells.](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Things_to_Come)

*Gold* (1934) ends with a fight and explosions in a labratory. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gold_(1934_film)

In the climax of *Frankenstein* (1931) a mob of peasants with pitchforks and torches storm a windmill. Some people might count that as battle.

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Frankenstein_(1931_film)

*Metropolis* (1927) climaxes with a workers revolt that may count as a battle.

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Metropolis_(1927_film)

*Aelita Queen of Mars* (1924) climaxes with a Martian revolt and battle scene.  https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Aelita

*The Mechanical Man* (1921) ends with a battle in an opera house between two robots. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Mechanical_Man

*20,000 Leagues Under the Sea* (1916) ends with a submarine torpedoing a ship. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/20,000_Leagues_Under_the_Sea_(1916_film)

*The Aerial Anarchists* (1911) involves airships and airplanes attacking and bombing. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Aerial_Anarchists

*The Airship Destroyer* (1909) shows a fleet of airships bombing an enemy country. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Airship_Destroyer

*A Trip to the Moon* (1902) ends as angry moon people chase the Earthlings back to their space vehicle, with the Earthlings killing many of their pursuers on the way. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/A_Trip_to_the_Moon

Thus I think that, depending on which of the above films (and others I couldn't remember or dig  up) count as having climatic battles, there may be science fiction films with climatic battles earlier than the fantasy film *Die Nibelungen* (1924).

Of course these science fiction examples show that there could have been fantasy films with climatic battles before *Die Nibelungen* (1924).

Answer (score 18):

**Most likely Fritz Lang's *Die Nibelungen* (1924)**

Before Fritz Lang created his masterpiece *Metropolis*, he did a 288 minute two-parter called *[Die Nibelungen](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Die_Nibelungen)* based on (but closer to) the same Teuronic legend (*Nibelungenlied*) as Richard Wagner's *Ring* cycle.

[image]

Part 2, *Kriemhilds Rache* (*Kriemhild's Revenge*) ends with an epic battle (or series of battles) lasting no less than 45 minutes.

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: What's a "288 two-parter"?

Comment: @Valorum I read the word "minutes" as missing.

Comment: I'll wait for some time but if nobody is able to find a film predating this, i'll accept your answer

Answer (score -1):

Would you count the climax of  Metropolis (1927) as a battle? Certainly its epic.

Comment: Note that this post-dates the previous answer.

Comment: Epic, but as pointed out by @DavidW, Die Nibelungen came before Metropolis